# object sorting using comparable interface

Tags: java

i have one class which have 4 int fields . i want to sort objects array by some mathematical operation on fields .I tried below code but sorting is not happening.

```
class Cust1 implements Comparable<Cust1>{

    int a;
    int o;
    int s;
    int p;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cust1 b) {
        if(this.a + this.s <= b.a + b.s)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }   
}

public class Test5 {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        Cust1[] cust = new Cust1[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n ;i++)
        {
            Cust1 a = new Cust1();
            String[] str = br.readLine().split(" "); 
            a.a = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
            a.o = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
            a.s = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
            a.p = Integer.parseInt(str[3]);
            cust[i] =a;
        }
        Arrays.sort(cust, new Comparator<Cust1>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Cust1 o1, Cust1 o2) {
                    return o1.compareTo(o2);
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately "sorting is not happening" doesn't really tell us much about what you *do* observe, or what the input data is, or the expected results, or the actual data. It would be really helpful if you could provide a [mcve] with hard-coded data instead of using user input, show what you expect the result to be, the actual results, and how far you've got debugging it. Also note that your `compareTo` comparison doesn't meet the requirements of comparators - I suggest you consult the documentation carefully.

Comment: `return Integer.compare(this.a + this.s <= b.a + b.s);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code snippet: you don't need to provide `Comparator`, since `Cust1` already implements `Comparable`. So, this should be enough:

```
Arrays.sort(cust);
```

Also, `Cust1` implementation of `Comparable` doesn't really tell, when one object `is less then` other. Probably, you meant something like this:

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cust1 b) {
        if(this.a + this.s < b.a + b.s) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.a + this.s > b.a + b.s) {
            return -1; 
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

But it's hard to tell, what exact implementation of `Comparable` should be without more details (for instance, for some reason fields `o` and `p` are not involved in comparison at all).

Answer (score 0):

You comparator work wrong. It should return:

- **>0** - current object is **greater** than another one
- **0** - current object is **equal** to another one
- **<0** - current object is **less** than another one

  class Cust1 implements Comparable {

  ```
  int a;
  int o;
  int s;
  int p;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Cust1 b) {
      return Integer.compare(a + s, b.a + b.s);
  }
  ```

  }

And you do not have to provide additional comparator to `Arrays.sort()` since `Cust1` already implements `Comparable`.